# Behavior of HTTP Task in Fowable

Tags: camunda, bpmn, flowable

I have three http tasks one-by-one say Http Task 1, Http Task 2, Http Task 3.
I want to understand how HTTP tasks behaves.

does flowable calls all these three Http tasks asynchronously without bothering the response of the previously called Http Tasks?

Or will the flowable wait for the Http Task 1 to complete (to receive response) before calling the Http Task 2 and so on?

I have a scenario where I need to call three APIs one-by-one, but I need to make sure, I am calling the other APIs after the completion of the first API.

Answer (score 1):

Flowable performs a synchronous request. The underlying implementation is Apache's Http Client. Configuration options are documented here: https://www.flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch07b-BPMN-Constructs/#http-task

You will be able to call the three APIs one after another as expected.